# What should be the best CNN model for Feature extraction of images for Image-Image search engine using LSH?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision

I have images something like the below:

[image]

`And like this:`

[image]

I have a huge data around 20M or so am I want to apply de-duplication and improve the search for this Image data. What I have in mind is to use Train and Extract Features from a CNN based Network and apply `LSH: Locality Sensitive Hashing` or `Approximate Nearest Neighbour: ANN`. I want to know that which model should I use to extract the features. I am thinking about training `Siamese` network (Maybe ResNet based architecture, if possible) or any of the pre trained `Imagenet` classifiers like pre trained VGG, ResNet, MobileNet etc. Which one should I use because I think I have a different use case because it is more like an `OCR` kind of approach rather than `Classifier`. For training purposes, I think I can have around 100K-1M images.

Also, can I use U-Net or AutoEncoders?